# Await Java 5 Futures in Kotlin Coroutines without blocking the Thread

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `suspend` function from which I want to return the result of a Java 5 `Future`. The future object comes from another library [Firebase Cloud Firestore- Admin SDK for Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) and provides a blocking call `get()` to retrieve the result of the said future.

My function looks like this-

```kotlin
suspend fun getPrefix(messageCreateEvent: MessageCreateEvent): String {

    val snapshot = db.collection("prefixes")
        .document(messageCreateEvent.guildId.get().asString())
        .get() //This returns a future
        .get() //Retrieves the future's result (Blocks thread; IDE gives warning)

    //Return the prefix
    return if (snapshot.exists())
        snapshot.getString("prefix") ?: DEFAULT_PREFIX
    else DEFAULT_PREFIX
}
```

### Solutions I have considered

The first thing that I considered was to look in `kotlinx.coroutine` for extensions to bridge the futures. While the extensions exist, they do only for `CompletionStatge`. So I decided to wrap the future into one ()-

```kotlin
val snapshot = CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync {
    db.collection("prefixes")
        .document(messageCreateEvent.guildId.get().asString())
        .get() // This returns a future
        .get() // Get the result
}.await()
```

I am quite inexperienced and not sure if this is was proper solution. I queried my question on a programming community, where a person recommended me to use a `Deferred`-

```kotlin
val deferred = CompletableDeferred<DocumentSnapshot>()
val future = db.collection("prefixes")
    .document(messageCreateEvent.guildId.get().asString())
    .get()

future.addListener(
    Runnable { deferred.complete(future.get()) },
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool()
)
            
val snapshot = deferred.await()
```

I've give it quite a time to search for a way to bridge futures to co-routines, there isn't even a similar question on SO. Through, I wouldn't be surprised if this question gets a duplicate mark.

Comment: how about https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8 ?

Comment: @minizibi Thanks for the comment. Yes I've checked them (and even mentioned in my question) there is no extension for awaiting on a `Future` object.

Comment: could you solve your problem? I'm stuck with the same issue :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this problem is the [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) function. The other non-obvious bit is that to add a callback to the `ApiFuture` you use a static method on `ApiFutures`.

Here's an extension function that implements `await()` on an `ApiFuture`.

```
        /**
         * Function to convert an ApiFuture into a coroutine return.
         */
        suspend fun <F : Any?, R : Any?> ApiFuture<F>.await(
            successHandler: (F) -> R,
        ): R {
            return suspendCoroutine { cont ->
                ApiFutures.addCallback(this, object : ApiFutureCallback<F> {
                    override fun onFailure(t: Throwable?) {
                        cont.resumeWithException(t ?: IOException("Unknown error"))
                    }

                    override fun onSuccess(result: F) {
                        cont.resume(successHandler(result))
                    }
                }, Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor())
            }
        }

/**
 * inline function to retrieve a document as a POJO from a DocumentReference
*/

suspend inline fun <reified T: Any>DocumentReference.toObject(): T? {
            return get().await<DocumentSnapshot, T?> {
                it.toObject(T::class.java)
            }
        }
```

Now you can write things like:

```kotlin
    suspend fun getUser(id: String): User? {
        return db.collection("users").document(id).toObject()

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`kotlinx-coroutines-guava`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/index.html) to do this

First convert `ApiFuture` to `ListenableFuture` using `ApiFutureToListenableFuture` then use `.await` to await completion of the listenableFuture without blocking a thread.

```kotlin
ApiFutureToListenableFuture(this).await()
```